# Get a value of an array within an array

Tags: php

Not sure on this one and was hoping you would be able to help me out on this one ...

Here's my code

```
Loader::library('file/types');
    $ih = Loader::helper('image');
    $names = explode("||",$this->tName);
    $urls = explode("||",$this->tUrl);
    $fIDs = explode("||",$this->fID);

    Loader::model('file');
    $i = Loader::helper('image');

    $v = array();
    $cc = 0;

    foreach ($names as $k=>$n){
      if (intval($fIDs[$k]) > 0 ) :
        $img = $test = File::getByID($fIDs[$k]);
        $fv = $img->getExtension();
        $ft = FileTypeList::getType($fv);
        $img = $ft->type == 1 ?  $img : false;  
      else :
        $img = false;
      endif;
    $v[$cc]['name']         = $n;
    $v[$cc]['url']          = $urls;
    $v[$cc]['src']          = $img ? $ih->getThumbnail($img,100,100)->src : false;
    $cc ++;
    }
    return $v;
```

And what i'm having issues with is getting the array values from $urls within this code. (5th last one)

```
foreach ($names as $k=>$n){
      if (intval($fIDs[$k]) > 0 ) :
        $img = $test = File::getByID($fIDs[$k]);
        $fv = $img->getExtension();
        $ft = FileTypeList::getType($fv);
        $img = $ft->type == 1 ?  $img : false;  
      else :
        $img = false;
      endif;
    $v[$cc]['name']         = $n;
    $v[$cc]['url']          = $urls;
    $v[$cc]['src']          = $img ? $ih->getThumbnail($img,100,100)->src : false;
    $cc ++;
    }
    return $v;
```

Thanks for all your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like this:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($names as $k=>$n){
  if (intval($fIDs[$k]) > 0 ) :
    $img = $test = File::getByID($fIDs[$k]);
    $fv = $img->getExtension();
    $ft = FileTypeList::getType($fv);
    $img = $ft->type == 1 ?  $img : false;  
  else :
    $img = false;
  endif;
$v[$cc]['name']         = $n;
$v[$cc]['url']          = $urls[$i]; //changed
$v[$cc]['src']          = $img ? $ih->getThumbnail($img,100,100)->src : false;
$cc ++;
$i++; //changed
}
return $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping through the names array using $k as the index, you can access the matching url with the same index.  So you could change the line to:

```
$v[$k]['url'] = $urls[$k];
```

There's no need to keep track of the index using the $cc variable since $k already represents the current index in the names array.  You are already accessing the fIDs array the same way (using $k).